# Twitter API 1.1 hashtag search

Tags: php, twitter, hashtag

decodeI am trying to search for tweets that contain a certain hashtag in php. i am using the recommended code but I just keep getting no results back from it. This is the code I am using to try and get the results.

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?q=#ManUtd&result_type=recent';

// Perform the request
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();
```

I have also tried:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?q=#ManUtd&result_type=recent';

// Perform the request
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                    ->performRequest();
var_dump(json_decode($response));
```

And I still get the same results. Anybody know why i am getting no data back from this

Comment: Are you sure your `$settings` are correct? Have you tried searching for `ManUtd` without the hashtag (I'm not sure if that could pose a problem)

Comment: yes the $settings are the same as i am using for other things and they all work. I havent touched anything in the TwitterAPIExchange but im guessing everything in that is correct

Comment: What happens when you URL encode the `#` so it's `%23`?

Comment: I still get nothing when i use  $getfield = '?q=%23ManUtd&result_type=recent';

Comment: Mm, just do your regular debugging first then to get a picture of your problem. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already found the answer to this, I'd suggest taking a look at the dev.twitter.com page on the [search endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). You can confirm the syntax for a search term by using the twitter.com/search web UI. The outcome of that search in the URL will give you the correct encoding for your search via the API.

As Terence noted, you do need to percent-encode the hash symbol (%23).

So, after a search via the web interface, the URL is:

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23ManUtd&src=typd
```

You'd want your query to include:

```
%23ManUtd
```

Check out the [Twitter guide on using the search endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).